# Add 1 to a value if name is equal to a string on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make some kind of inventory. So when on the second sheet I add a name of a certain product, it adds 1 up to the inventory I had in the first sheet in row E for that product. This for a list of names put in the 2nd sheet instead of just 1 name like tried out in the VBA code here.

After I am done with the list I should be able to clear sheet 2 and the values stay saved.
When I try this it gives an error and I just don't know how to make it work with letting it go over the entire list.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "E").Value
    For Each cell In Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A:A")
        If cell.Value = Sheets("Sheets2").Cells(1, "A").Value Then
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a little unclear. `Sheet1` has a value in `E1`.  Say "20".  As you go through Sheet1 column A, if that value matches the value in `Sheet2 A1`, then add that number to 20....?  Also, what error are you getting? Perhaps you need `Dim x as Long` instead of `Integer`, depending on what the values are.

Comment: It should then add 1 to the 20 in E1. It just gives an issue i ask to debug and it shows me the 3rd line in yellow, most likely a coding mistake but can't figure out which one

Comment: Is is always E1, or are you keeping count on a row by row bases?

Comment: You should look into excel built-in SUMIF function. Check this example https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/inventory-management-using-sumif-function/

Comment: @Sithu it will take vba as the OP has stated that once the code is run the reference sheet will be cleared and updated.  SUMIF as a formula is live and will return to 0 when the data on sheet2 is cleared.  also COUNTIF is more appropriate.

Comment: Should Sheet 1 in `For Each` line not be in quotes e.g. Sheets("Sheet1")...

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking that `x` represents the cell, but it is a memory variable that starts with the Value in E1 on Sheet1.

If you want the range to increase then make the variable a range and set it to the range desired, or skip that all together:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cell as Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In Intersect(.Range("A:A"),.UsedRange)
            .Range("E1").value = .Range("E1").value + Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"),cell.Value)
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ooh, this is much more elegant, nice thinking with `COUNTIF()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click2()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell as Range
    x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' assuming Col. A has most data
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = Sheets("Sheets2").Range("A1").Value Then
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    Debug.Print "x is now " & x
    ' Put the new value in E1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = x
End Sub
```

I didn't do too much, just shortened the range so you don't loop through all of column A.  Added `Dim cell as Range`, and put quotes around the `Sheet1` in the `For` loop start. (That's where the error was coming from on that line).  You can do `Sheet1.Range()`, or `Sheets("Sheet1").Range`, but not `Sheets(Sheet1).Range` without some additional coding/weird variable setup.